# Eclipse has an internal error during Launching

Tags: eclipse

I am facing this issue with eclipse (Its eclipse Oxygen) I am unable to run a simple Java program
This happen after I modified the project to be a Maven project.
what I tried so far:
I updated the software using (help > check for updates)
deleted the Workspace, and created a new one.

[image: printScreen]

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-12-21 13:15:48.670
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching MailProcessor".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.isModularJava(JavaRuntime.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.isModularConfiguration(JavaRuntime.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.computeJREEntry(JavaRuntime.java:2341)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.computeUnresolvedClasspath(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.RuntimeClasspathProvider.computeUnresolvedClasspath(RuntimeClasspathProvider.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.computeUnresolvedRuntimeClasspath(JavaRuntime.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getBootpathExt(AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getVMSpecificAttributesMap(AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate._OT$callOrig(JavaLaunchDelegate.java:71)
    at org.objectteams.Team._OT$terminalCallNext(Team.java:598)
    at org.objectteams.Team._OT$callNext(Team.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.internal.debug.adaptor.launching.JDTLaunchingAdaptor._OT$callNext(JDTLaunchingAdaptor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.internal.debug.adaptor.launching.JDTLaunchingAdaptor._OT$callReplace(JDTLaunchingAdaptor.java:56)
    at org.objectteams.Team._OT$callAllBindings(Team.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.callAllBindings(JavaLaunchDelegate.java)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.launch(JavaLaunchDelegate.java)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Comment: Is "MailProcessor" your project's name?

Comment: Pleas try a more recent release, like 2019-06, which have received a bunch of improvements on many topics, including support for modular java.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I faced a similar issue in the past, you can try the following:

1. Exit Eclipse
2. Go to your workspace folder in the file explorer
3. Look for the .metadata folder and delete it
4. Re-open Eclipse

Hope it works.

Comment: try deleting .settings folder and .project and import your project into a new workspace as an existing maven project.

Comment: Yeah this activity will clean off the workspace completely and give you the fresh workspace. You just need to import the projects again and it works fine. No need to delete .settings and.project folders

Comment: For those of you trying to get their workspace Maven projects back after deleting .metadata: Hit File->Import...->Maven->Existing Projects->Browse->Ok

Comment: Workspace character encoding may need to be reapplied

Comment: Wow this deleted all my projects and lost everything and many work I had done... thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I had Similar issue, Just restarted eclipse it works automatically

Comment: Restarting doesn't adress the root cause.

Comment: It will solve temporary again if you build means this issue may be occured again

Answer (score 1):

for me it happens when in `run configuration` I click on `configure` next to `PHP server`

Solve it by clicking `new` instead

Answer (score 1):

Finally got solution don't need to delete .metadata or .settings just need to add this in environmental variables In System variables   `_JAVA_OPTIONS -Xmx1024M`